# Scanner.hasNext String matching in Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing, text, java.util.scanner

I am parsing a text file that contains some text as shown below:

```
Level1
Some-text-here
Level2
Some-text-here
Level3
Some-text-here
```

I have implemented the code where it parses the file and tries to count the number of occurrences of "Level" in the file. This is how I am doing it:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(inPath));
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Level");
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    if(scanner.hasNext(p))  {
        ++lastLevelCreatedWas;
    }
    scanner.next();
}
```

However the 'if' condition never gets hit because hasNext(p) is trying to find the exact match of "Level" and would just ignore the words "Level1", "Level2" and so on. How am I supposed to make it consider any word that contains the keyword "Level" in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Scanner.useDelimiter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29)

Try this :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(inPath));
scanner.useDelimiter("Level");
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    ++lastLevelCreatedWas;
    scanner.next();
}
```

It while go to the next "Level" token as you want.

Comment: Yeah that did the trick. What if I wanted to do it by matching a string? Would I be using something like Patter.compile("Level" ,Pattern.COMMENTS) ??

Comment: You way want to use `scanner.useDelimiter("Level\\d+");`, meaning `"Level"` followed by 1-n digits, if you want to consume the level number too

Answer (score 2):

hasNext, getNext and other similar methods work only when delimiter is set.

Invoke `useDelimiter` method to set the delimiter to the Scanner instance.